# How to convert REST API's request body of String datatype into JSON Object in Node JS and test that in Postman?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose

I have a Node JS application running with Express and mongodb. I have a use case where my device sends data to my server. It might be JSON data or Comma-Separated String(**Only String, not CSV file**). I need to check which type of data is coming and manipulate that to JSON if request body would be a String. When I was trying to display the data type of data being sent to the server, it's displaying as "**object**" even after giving the "**String**" data as input. And the operation is getting successful but data is not inserting into the database. Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Sample Payload(request.body) would be,

```
"heat:22,humidity:36,deviceId:sb-0001"
```

Expected response is,

```
{
      "heat": "22",
      "humidity": "36",
      "deviceId": "sb-0001"
}
```

Comment: Post your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

@Aravind Actually typeof will returns "string" if operand is a string.So please check whether the string is coming or not in body, because if it is null then typeof will return "object".

Comment: when I'm giving JSON String, the payload is looking something like this. **INPUT**: ```"{"heat":22,"humidity":36,"deviceId":"sb-0001"}"```  **OUTPUT**:```{"\"{\"heat\":22,\"humidity\":36,\"deviceId\":\"sb-0001\"}\"":""}``` and an error was thrown, **Unexpected token \\ in JSON at position 4**

Comment: if I'm giving Input like, ```"heat:22,humidity:36,deviceId:sb-0001"```, the console showing the payload like you said, ```{}```

Comment: I think you should escapes the Json object like  {"heat":22,"humidity":36,"deviceId":"sb-0001"}  (by avoiding "" on both sides of Json "{"heat":22,"humidity":36,"deviceId":"sb-0001"}") and then you will get something like : {\"heat\":22,\"humidity\":36,\"deviceId\":\"sb-0001\"}.  After that when I do JSON.parse('{\"heat\":22,\"humidity\":36,\"deviceId\":\"sb-0001\"}'), I'll get the parsed JSON like { heat: 22, humidity: 36, deviceId: 'sb-0001' }

Answer (score 0):

> I need to check which type of data is coming and manipulate that to JSON ...

HTTP is build upon the media-type concept that defines the syntax used in the payload of that type as well as the semantics of the elements used within that payload. You might take a look at how HTML defines [forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html) to get a grip what a media-type specification should include. Through [content negotiation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4) client and server agree on a common media-type and thus a representation format to exchange payloads for supported by both. This simply increases interoperability between the participants as they exchange data in well-defined, hopefully standardized, representation formats both understand and support.

Through [Accept](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) headers a receiver can state preferences on which types to receive, including a weighting scheme to indicate that a certain representation format is preferred over an other one but the recipient is also fine with the other one, while a [Content-Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) header will indicate the actual representation format being sent.

[RFC 7111](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7111) defines `text/csv` for CSV based representations and [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) specifies `application/json` for JSON payload. As the sender hopefully knows what kind of document it sends to the receiver, you can use this information to distinguish the payload on the receiver side. Note however that according to Fielding true REST APIs [must use representation formats that support hypertext-driven interaction flows](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) to allow clients to take further actions upon the payload received without having to invoke some external documentation. Both, JSON and CSV, by default don't support such an interaction model, that is abreviated with the term HATEOAS. For your simple scenario the content type negotiation might though be sufficient enough to solve your needs.

In terms of processing CSV and converting the data to JSON this is simply a matter of splitting up the CSV string on the delimiter symbol (`,` in the sample) to key-value pairs and then splitting the key and values further on the `:` symbol and adding these to a new JSON object. There is also a [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson) library available at NPM that you might utilize in such a case.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. But am not using any csv file in payload. It's just a String which consists of comma separated values.